# Who is the man?

Tags: word-usage

Could you tell me the word interpretation?
In this case, does "the man" mean Eshley or the general man?

"You seem to forget that the cook has neuralgia," said Eshley; "she may be just dozing off into a merciful sleep and your outcry will waken her. Consideration for others should be the guiding principle of people in our station of life."
"**The man** is mad!" exclaimed Adela tragically. A moment later it was Adela herself who appeared to go mad.

quoted from [the stalled ox](http://www.eastoftheweb.com/short-stories/UBooks/Stal819.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

The speaker, Adela, is talking about Eshley. This is clear from the discussion and disagreement that the two have that lead to this statement.  The usage of *the man* is idiomatic and can be interpreted as *he*. You can also say things such as *the boy is mad* or *the woman is mad*. All these would refer to specific, real individuals in the context.

Unlike we do for other species, (example: *the cheetah*, *the whale*), we  don't  use *the man* to talk about *the  general man*. We could use *the human* to refer to the species, or something more scientific such as  *the homosapien*. To refer to males in general, we often use *men*, as in *men are great* or *men are scum*. We could say *men are mad*.

Answer (score -1):

"the man", I think, refers to **the cook**. As the former already says, the cook is nalargic; the latter might be referring to the cook as mad.

Comment: _**she** may be just dozing off ... outcry will waken **her**_ is a little difficult to reconcile with the _man_ being the cook.

Comment: But the cook is apparently female.  I'm guessing that "the man" refers to someone else who was mentioned in previous paragraphs.

Comment: @HotLicks The story is very short and all the characters are mentioned in the question extract. 'The man' is Eshley and Adela is appealing theatrically to the universe at large.